# How many servers needed to handle such a large data

Tags: performance, bigdata, database-performance

We have 1 million dataset and each dataset is around 180mb. SO the total size of our data is around 185T. Each dataset is plain DEL file with only three columns. The first two columns is the row key and the last one is the value of the row. For example, the first column is A, the second is B the third is C. The value of A is the dataset number, so A is fixed in one dataset and its range is from 1-1million. B is the position number, B can range from 1 to 3 million.

What we are planning to do is given a any set of non-overlapping ranges of B like from 1-1000, 10000-13000, 16030-17000...., we calculate the sum of the values of each dataset over all these ranges, and return the top 200 dataset number(A) with in seconds.

Do any one expertised in bigdata have any idea on how many severs we will need to handle this case? My boss believe 10 servers (16 cores each) can do it with a budget of $50,000. Do you think it's feasible?

Comment: It's a bit late and the question is closed, but if that data is somewhat static or data is only added at the end of each file with growing position numbers, this could actually be done in under a second (with up to 5 ranges) on a single PC (assuming there is HD (NAS?) read access of around 100MB/second and the C values are normal numbers). This would be using C/C++ code and a more optimized data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that services such as Microsoft Azure can be your friend in this case. I think that your budget will go further using "pay as you use" services. You can decide how many servers / instances you would like to use to crunch your data.

I do think that one slight problem might be the way your data is currently formatted. I would most certainly look at using Azure table storage possibly and first work on getting your data in a service such as that. Once that has been complete, you now have a more "queryable" and reliable data store. From there you can use your language of choice to interact with that data. Using table storage, you can create partition keys.

Once you have your partitions that you would like to use, you can then create a service that you would perhaps supply a partition or more likely partition range, which it will process. You will be able to adjust the size of your instances and also what hardware should drive them, with something like this in place you can then determine an average on how long it would take 1 instance to process x records. Perhaps you could write some logs as to the performance.

Once you have your logs, it will be simple to determine how long the process would take with reasonable accuracy. you can then start adding more instances to your service, thus starting to work through the data at a faster pace.

Table storage was also designed to work with big datasets, so going through the documentation on this, you will find many key features that you could use.

there are honestly many ways in which this problem could be solved, this is simply one option that I have used in the past and it worked for me at the time.

I would make sure that if this was a viable option for you, to place your data and services in the same data centre. While I assume you have some form of sequence in your files, you could also persist placeholders storing your sum values for future use and should your data grow in the future you could simply add the new data and run your services again to update the system.

I would not go on this journey without making sure that you can persist your sum values in some or other way, otherwise should you need to get the values again in the future you will again need to start from the beginning again.

I managed to find one quick write up about the services mentioned above working with big data. Perhaps it might be able to help you further. http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/12/working-with-154-million-records-on.html

Comment: Louis, Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, I have tried the amazon AWS services, the performance is acceptable but the expense is unaffordable. How is the price of MS Azure? My boss prefers to have a local cluster of machines, so he hoped me can solve the problem with just 10 servers. As far as I know, it's not quite possible at least not for big data techniques like HBase

Comment: I find the MS pricing fantastic, you can check pricing on their calculator page here, http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=data-management. You can of course do this on internal servers, although this is one of those instances where I would seriously consider using a language that fits the problem, possibly something like c++, it seems as if with the amount of data you are talking about, every second gained will count in the long run. sounds like a fantastic project too. I hope you enjoy the path to the solution. sounds like fun.

Comment: In fact, I forgot that with todays compilers and good code, you can almost reach the same results with C# as you can with c++. sorry for that, for a moment I was stuck in my old c++ frame of mind. :)

Comment: strongly agree with you on this point. But unfortunately, the Hadoop System seems build on Java. Do you know any similar system built on C++ or C#?

Comment: sure there are a few resources you can look at, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/data_otaku/archive/2013/08/14/hadoop-for-net-developers.aspx or even http://www.amazedsaint.com/2013/03/taming-big-data-with-c-using-hadoop-on.html

Comment: one more point, I would not worry about how many servers you need, that I would bet very very little people would be able to guess right, while there are people who may have worked with that size before, formats, languages, network, hardware all being variables in the equation will simply give a too broad range to work with. I would get 1 server setup, write your code, perfect it and get that server to its max output, this will tell you in your setup more accurately how many servers are required to achieve the result in X time.